# android: Asynchronous task along with multiple handlers

Tags: android, asynchronous, handler

I am new to android and I am stuck with a complicated requirement.My android application is using a .Net web service to retreive images from server along with the duration for which images has to be shown

I have 3 requirements.
1) Display the image retrieved from server and show in the control. Duration will also be retreived along with image.
2) During half the duration, call web service and retrieve 2nd image and mantain in cache
3) The first image should be shown in the control till the duration finishes. After the time finish, display the second image from cache.

Ex:Image 1 retrieved and displayed in control with duration 10s. During 5th sec, second call to webservice retrieving image 2. Till 10th sec the first image should remain displayed, the image retrieved through second call should be updated in the control after this 10th sec.. The entire process repeats .

Code: I am using Asynchronous Task to invoke web service.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(final Wrapper wrapperObj) {
                Handler hand = new Handler();
                Handler hand1 = new Handler();
                if(isFirstTime ) // First time, directly set image.
                {
                    UploadMediaToControl(wrapperObj);
                    durationForViewingMedia = wrapperObj.Duration;
                }
                hand.postDelayed(run1, (wrapperObj.Duration / 2)); // Wait for half the time. This handler invokes Web Service in run()
                hand1.postDelayed(run2, durationForViewingMedia); // Wait for the time to complete. This handler handles image setting to control inside run.

        }
```

Is this right approach. The main focus is the second handler should wait until the first image duration finishes. To point out, my first handler invokes web service. So by the time the second handler wait finishes, my control would have come to OnPostExecute after retrieving the web service through first handler. In such a case, will the handlers keep on creating or will they wait for the handler to finish..I believe using thread would make the application unresponsive. Hence I don't prefer that approach. Please help!!!

Thanks